# GraphAPI error says that this user cannot be invited because the domain of the user's email address is a verified domain of this directory

Tags: .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I use the GraphAPI to add users from my code to inject users into Azure AD B2C. I use the following snippet:

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
.Create(_config["ClientId"])
.WithTenantId(_config["TenantId"])
.WithClientSecret(_config["ClientSecret"])
.Build();

ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

var invitation = new Invitation
{
    InvitedUserEmailAddress = user.Mail,
    InvitedUserDisplayName = user.Name + " " + user.Surname,
    InviteRedirectUrl = "https://redirect.net/",
    SendInvitationMessage = true
};

await graphClient.Invitations
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(invitation);
```

The last line fails with the error

> This user cannot be invited because the domain of the user's email address is a verified domain of this directory.

I checked the permissions for the app -> b2c and everything seems to be set well. I'm using .net6 now but earlier I used .net3.1 and this snippet worked without throwing any error. Has someone stumbled upon an error like this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Users who share the same email domain as the backup tenant can only be added if they are Azure Active Directory members in your organization.
To add a new user to AAD:

1. Log in to the Azure portal using the organization's User Administrator role.
2. From any page, search and choose Azure Active Directory.
3. Choose Users, then click New user.
4. Fill up the user's information on the User page.
5. Copy the Password box's automatically produced password. This password must be given to the user in order for them to sign in for the first time.
6. Choose Create.
   After that, your Azure AD organisation receives the newly created user. Also, don't forget to add the user as a member of Azure AD rather than a guest.

**References:**
[Allow or block invitations to B2B users from specific organizations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/allow-deny-list)

Comment: The user I'm trying to invite trough the GraphAPI is already part of my AAD. Also under Collaboration restrictions, I have Allow invitations to be sent to any domain (most inclusive) selected.